# EF5 to EF6 upgrade - navigation properties are broken

Tags: c#, entity-framework, upgrade, relationship

I used nuget to upgrade EF5 to EF6, and somewhere a breaking change was introduced for my solution. I discovered this when running one of my unit tests (it affects everything though). In each test, I init by doing this:

```
// warm up EF.
using (var context = new ReportingDbContext())
{
     context.Database.Initialize(false); // <-- boom!
}
// init the service
_inventoryService = new InventoryService();
```

It tosses me this exception:

```
The property 'EmployeeID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.
```

The strange thing this, everything was just peachy on EF5. I went hunting through my models (I have a bunch) and found everywhere that EmployeeID lives. They all look like this:

```
[Table("mytablename")]
public class CSATEntity
{

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CSATID { get; set; }

    // foreign keys
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    // nav props
    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual CompanyEntity CompanyEntity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public virtual EmployeeEntity EmployeeEntity { get; set; }
    ... more props
```

The exception doesn't note which model is jacked up, or if all of them are. What is the best way to hunt this down?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing namespace from

```
 System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext

 System.Data.Objects to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
```

Take a look at this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469466. It explains how to upgrade to `Entity Framework 6`

Comment: I don't have any references like that in any of my using statements. My repository classes use System.Data.Entity, and when I check the actual references in the solution explorer I see EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer and no System.Data.Entity so I assume that using statement is referring to the now correct EF6 DLL. If it means anything, I'm using code first.

Comment: @BillSambrone According to this msdn article Installing the `EF6 NuGet package` should automatically remove any references to `System.Data.Entity` from your project for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469466

Comment: It did remove it from the references, but not from the using statements inside the actual classes. When I manually remove it, I lose my DbContext class. Is there an alternative I should be using for the actual using statement?

Comment: @BillSambrone We faced a similar problem few days day when we upgraded one of our project to `EF6`. changing the namespaces in `Context.tt.cs` from `System.Data.Objects` to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects` fixed it. Hope this helps

Comment: @BillSambrone - were you able to fix the problem? I'm facing the same one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334685/after-upgrade-to-ef6-the-property-cannot-be-configured-as-a-navigation-propert?lq=1

Comment: Nope, I gave up. I'm sticking with EF5 for now and will tackle this again when EF 6.2 appears.